# Trouble running local WordPress in Google App Engine

Tags: redirect, installation, localhost, local-installation

Following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress).

Installed MySQL, Python and Google App Engine PHP SDK on a Windows 8 PC. Perfect!

Created an app for WordPress, created database and user on localhost and edited WordPress config accordingly.

Started the app in the Google App Engine Launcher. Clicking Browse leads to blank page at `http://localhost:8080/`

Hmmm...

Checked logs, found

```
2013-11-26 17:56:18 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', 
'--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000',
'C:\\Users\\CsillamVilag\\Documents\\development-appengine\\arcfestesmintak']" 
INFO     2013-11-26 17:56:19,805 devappserver2.py:660] 
Skipping SDK update check. 
WARNING  2013-11-26 17:56:19,813 api_server.py:331] 
Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. 
INFO     2013-11-26 17:56:19,822 api_server.py:138] 
Starting API server at: http://localhost:53853 
INFO     2013-11-26 17:56:19,826 dispatcher.py:171] 
Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080 
INFO     2013-11-26 17:56:19,828 admin_server.py:117] 
Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000 
INFO     2013-11-26 17:56:21,828 module.py:617] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

Pretty certain the Python for Windows package I used included PIL. Not sure where to go from here...

If I go to `http://localhost:8080/wp-admin` though, I get

```
Warning: chdir(): Invalid argument (errno 22) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php\setup.php on line 42

Warning: require(wordpress/wp-admin/wp-admin/install.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php\setup.php on line 103

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'wordpress/wp-admin/wp-admin/install.php' (include_path='C:\Users\CsillamVilag\Documents\development-appengine\arcfestesmintak;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\php\sdk') in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php\setup.php on line 103
```

In the error returned at `http://localhost:8080/wp-admin/` I see `/wp-admin/wp-admin/install.php`

Obviously `install.php` cant be found. It is in `/wp-admin/` not in `/wp-admin/wp-admin/`
Not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Google App Engine doesn't support WordPress 3.7.1 (something that's not documented anywhere). Downgrading to WordPress 3.5.1 (the version mentioned in Google's instructions) made it work - `http://localhost:8080` was forwarded to WordPress Install page.

Comment: this is actually very interesting and very bad. If you can't run the latest WP then you should not use the service. Have you tried to upgrade after installing 3.5.1?

Comment: Yup, terrible! Haven't managed to deploy yet. Will try upgrading after deployment, and report back.